# When using sub-domains for a Django site, how can you share django logins across sub-domains on localhost?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to let the same user session span across:

- site.com
- sub1.site.com
- sub2.site.com

I got this to work in production by setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to ".site.com", but it doesn't work for me on localhost/dev servers. How do you get it to work for localhost sub-domains? When I change the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` on the dev server to the production website domain or ".localhost", django auth logins completely stop working (I'm unable to ever login, no cookie is created on localhost).

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate, see this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442017/subdomains-and-logins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442017/subdomains-and-logins)

Comment: See "[Add subdomain to localhost URL](/q/19016553/90527)".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I got a workaround solution, but couldn't use localhost.  I could only get it working for a test ".com" domain that maps to 127.0.0.1.

In my /etc/hosts file (on OSX:)

```
    127.0.0.1  test.com
    127.0.0.1  sub1.test.com
    127.0.0.1  sub2.test.com
```

Then on my development settings.py:

```
    SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=".test.com"
```

I could not get this working with plain "localhost", it seemed I needed the ".com" string in there to get it working.  So then I could login and have cross subdomain auth cookies using sub1.test.com:8000 and sub2.test.com:8000 in my browser.