# django: Is it possible to log a user into a subdomain, from another domain?

Tags: django, session, authentication, subdomain

The thing is. I have one django app serving different sites.

site1.myapp.com
site2.myapp.com

The users login via a 3rd party SSO system which is then redirected(inkl. a valdiation POST) to https://myapp.com/auth/

However. since my users all belong to only 1 "site" i would like myapp.com/auth/
to log the user into the relevant site, ex. site1.myapp.com or site2.myapp.com and then redirect them to that site…

Is this at all possible?? or should i go about this in a totally different way? :)

I should mention that when it comes to the general usage of the app I have subdomain middleware to ensure that the users always only visit the subdomain(and data) that their account is valid for.

The reason I want to use subdomains is to make it simple for the users to remember their account url, while maintaining the pros of having to maintain just one django app.

thanks. hope you can help :)

kind regards.

pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django you have the notion of [sites](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/). You can create your own [log in view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). If it's not enough, you can create your own [authentification backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/authbackends/).

Comment: Well, that doesn't really cut it. I need to be able to log a user in to his "own app", but this has to be done on the main domain. I don't see where the sites part helps me here?? I'm thinking more in terms of sessions, redirects, cookies, domain names etc. but thats about as far as I've gotten :-S

Comment: Sites let you separate codes and database entries according to a site. But a site is whatever you decide it to be, including a subdomaine. So you link a user to a "site", you create your login page, and on login, you get the user site and you redirect.

Answer (score 15):

*I know this question is old, but since Google brought me here I'll add these links*

This answer touches on (A) authentication across subdomains and (B) detecting which subdomain is in use to potentially redirect the user

**A.1. If you want to allow all (wildcard) subdomains
*.myapp.com**, this is achieved by adding one line to settings.py:

`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=".myapp.com"`

Detailed [here (SO, 2009)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444744/870121), [here (SO, 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118380/870121) and [in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN)

> Note: login now won't work on localhost, so you have two choices if
>   you need to log in and out on localhost:
>   1: comment out that line in settings.py, or
>   2: amend your /etc/hosts file to include the following:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 127.0.0.1 dev.myapp.com
> ```
>
> Now you can visit `dev.myapp.com` in your browser, and it'll actually be talking to 127.0.0.1, not your live
>   website. (Now, across `dev.myapp.com`, `site1.myapp.com`,
>   `site2.myapp.com` and `myapp.com`, if you log in/out of one, you'll be
>   logged in/out of them all.)

**A.2. If you want to allow cross-authentication between just those two subdomains**, i.e., they won't be logged into `site3.myapp.com`, then it gets [a bit more complicated](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/S4gGf_4bKPQ/-eEitaXQTYoJ)

**B. To view the subdomain being used**
There are fancier packages to manage subdomains in django, but you could just look crudely at request.META['HTTP_HOST']:

```
try:
    http_host = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    # alternative: http_host = request.get_host()
except KeyError:
    http_host = None
    print "Can't find HTTP_HOST"

if http_host and '.myapp.com' in http_host:
    subdomain = http_host.split('.myapp.com')[0]
else:
    subdomain = ''
```

Then check if you're happy with the `request.user` using this `subdomain`.
Use something like [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) to send them to a different subdomain if you like. If you've done A.1 or A.2 above, in your app's eyes, they're the same user (already logged in) in the new subdomain.myapp.com after being redirected (they don't have to log in again).

Example: if a user creates an account with ireland.myapp.com and you want to keep them always on that site, then when they try to visit usa.myapp.com, they'll still be logged in, you can identify them and send them back to ireland.myapp.com (fictitious example, not a metaphor for immigration!)