# Set login session for sub domain from main domain in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a main domain `example.com` and a subdomain `tenant.example.com`. A user comes to `http://example.com/login` and logs In, By default, Django set a session cookie for `example.com`.

What I want is that Django set the session cookie for `tenant.example.com` instead of `example.com`.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django: Is it possible to log a user into a subdomain, from another domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814760/django-is-it-possible-to-log-a-user-into-a-subdomain-from-another-domain)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I didn't get the perfect answer, I don't wanna use the wildcard `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=".myapp.com"`, How can do this without it?